# Need to pass variables with jquery $.post()

Tags: jquery

I want to pass variable with jQuery `$.post()`.

My code

```
$('#unit_id').change(function() {
        var unit_id = 'sdf';
        var user_id = 'werwe';
        $.post("test.php", { 'user_id': +user_id, 'unit_id': +unit_id, },
          function(data){
            console.log(data.user_id);
            console.log(data.unit_id);
          }, "json");
    });
```

But this post result like:

```
unit_id NaN
user_id NaN
```

why this is `NaN`?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)`, what does that show?

Comment: its a test code so no need to view json results. i need only post multy variable in test.php

Answer (score 3):

Why are you appending `+` with `variable`?

[$.post() doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) says that parameter `data` accepts `A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.` and so need of appending `+` with the `variable`.

Change this from.

```
$.post("test.php", { 'user_id': +user_id, 'unit_id': +unit_id, },
```

to

```
$.post("test.php", { 'user_id': user_id, 'unit_id': unit_id, },
```

Comment: This is true. you should explain why.

Comment: first time i use $.post("test.php", { 'user_id': user_id, 'unit_id': unit_id, }, but its don't show any result, let see

Comment: @Shawon your code will work on changing this.